# Minified files and ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I used ui-router, when the file is not minifed or when I used the already minified file everything is working.

But I have a gulp task that takes all the library and minify them using "uglify()" (this is necessary because some of the library doesn't have a minified version.

So my question is: Do you know why uglify() doesn't work with UI-router

The error I get is:
d.get is not a function
at < a ui-sref="flight" class="ng-scope">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue one time, use the mangle option:

.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))

It's not ideal because the files won't be as minified as possible but it's working for me